# How to multiply 2D arrays with conditions in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, conditional-statements

I am trying to accomplish in Excel following case but I am not able to make it work. Could you please help?

1. I have got given volume data for asseblies (as example Ive choosed bikes)
2. In second part of table I have number of parts needed for each assembly

The task is to calculate quantity of each part. 
Example: PART 1 = (2 x 50) + (1 x 250) + (1 x 400) + (1 x 300) = 1050.

The problem is, that I can not touch/sort the upper table with bikes to be able to use simple SUMPRODUCT?

[image]

Link to excel sheet: [Excel sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x6chrfaq70i1vk6/AACt5AAgl1Nw9l7uUvpytCM5a?dl=0)

Could you please give me an advise at least which direction should I look?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to try to fit a function to your problem, instead, you need to think how you can change your solution and pick the functions or formulas that will help you do this easily.

Multiply the values of the upper table and at the bottom make a row of totals (sums). Then simply use a formula that multiplies each row of the lower table to that row.

Download the Excel file here: https://ufile.io/e6xbl

[image]

[image]